# two .on event handlers, only 1 firing

Tags: jquery

I have two event handlers:

```
$('body').on("blur", ".required", {requiredBlur: true}, checkData);
$('body').on("click", 'input[name="personality"]', {personalityClick:true}, checkData);
```

`.required` is one of many input text fields and `input[name="personality"]` is a series of checkboxes.  So when a `.required` input text field is in focus and I click one of the checkboxes the blur event fires.  But the click event doesn't fire for the checkboxes.  So in effect, I must click on a checkbox twice to select it.

Should both fire or am I missing something?

mike

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
$('.required').live('change', {requiredBlur: true}, checkData);
$('input[name="personality"]').live('click', {personalityClick: true}, checkData)
```

Comment: mmm...`live()` is deprecated in favor of `on()`.

Comment: @elclanrs its is too, damm API changes.

Comment: Well that works...thanks.  But the API says "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers."

Answer (score 0):

According to Quirksmode blur and focus don't work on radio buttons and checkboxes in Firefox Mac or Webkit (Chrome/ Safari) if use user uses a mouse ([source](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/blurfocus.html)). This means you're going to have to rely on the `change` event most likely to get full coverage.

In my [simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/slace/TPpH5/) `on` works fine for this but you'll have to ensure you've got your logic supporting the fact that the events fire a whole lot more than you initially designed for. For reference here's a [good explanation of the different way to attach handles using jQuery](http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/02/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live.html).

Comment: The OP is using blur on a text field and click on a checkbox.  Both of those should work.  Your comment is about blur on a checkbox which is not what is being used here.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I bound each event handler to a different function.  So instead of binding each event to checkData() I just create two separate functions, one for each event.